# Clarification around the concept of Path, Mount Point and Prefix in http4s

Tags: scala, purely-functional, http4s

I'm trying to clarify some concept that confuse me slightly around http4s path.

Quoting the documentation,

> Path info
>
> Path matching is done on the request’s pathInfo. Path info is the request’s URI’s path after the following:
>
> - the mount point of the service
> - the prefix, if the service is composed with a Router
> - the prefix, if the service is rewritten with TranslateUri
>
> Matching on `request.pathInfo` instead of `request.uri.path` allows multiple services to be composed without rewriting all the path matchers.

I would like to clarify the notion of mount point and prefix.

1. Can some give an example of a mount point definition vs a prefix ?
2. Can a service have both a mount point and prefix that are not the same ?

I suspect that the mount point in this example is `/hello`?

```scala
HttpRoutes.of[IO] {
        case GET -> Root / "hello" => Ok("hello")
}
```

3. When writing the below code, we are defining 2 prefixes `/` and `/api`, but are they also consider mount point ?

```scala
val services = tweetService <+> helloWorldService

val httpApp  = Router("/" -> helloWorldService, "/api" -> services).orNotFound
```

Because quoting the documentation, we have:

> We start from a BlazeServerBuilder, and then mount the
> helloWorldService under the base path of / and the remainder of the
> services under the base path of /api

4. For the second prefix `/api`, what is the **Root** of the `helloWorldService` in

```scala
case GET -> Root / "hello"
```

is it `/api`, as in `Root = /api` ?

5. What is the mount point of the `helloWorldService` in that circumstance and what is the prefix ?

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting the first sentence. The prefixes and mount point are _not_ included in the `pathInfo` that is used for path matching. So a service doesn't have to know at which path it will eventually be mounted.

Comment: Would you mind please sharing the appropriate interpretation? It would greatly help me